# GCP Organizational Policy Deny All external IP with select VM exceptions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, terraform-provider-gcp

### Desired Outcome

I want to allow specific GCE VMs to have public IP when we have an organizational policy that blocks external IP addresses on GCE.

I want to manage the policy (policies) in terraform.

#### Assumptions

- VM name is known and deployed

#### resources

- [terraform resource](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/org_policy_policy)
- [gcp doc Organization Policy Service](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/overview)
- [gcp doc Using constraints](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/using-constraints)
- [Organization policy constraints](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/organization-policy/org-policy-constraints)

Answer (score 0):

```
resource "google_org_policy_policy" "global_vm_external_ip_deny" {
  name   = "organizations/153718440496/policies/compute.vmExternalIpAccess"
  parent = "organizations/153718440496"

  spec {
    rules {
      deny_all = "TRUE"
    }
  }
}

resource "google_org_policy_policy" "primary" {
  name   = "projects/one-vm-public-ip/policies/compute.vmExternalIpAccess"
  parent = "projects/one-vm-public-ip"

  spec {
    inherit_from_parent = false
    rules {
      values {
        allowed_values = ["projects/one-vm-public-ip/zones/us-central1-a/instances/org-policy-exception"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

#### Outputs & Verification

```bash
 gcloud compute instances create whatever-should-fail --project=one-vm-public-ip                                        

# ERROR: (gcloud.compute.instances.create) Could not fetch resource:
 - Constraint constraints/compute.vmExternalIpAccess violated for project 347995204441. Add instance projects/one-vm-public-ip/zones/us-east1-c/instances/whatever-should-fail to the constraint to use external IP with it.
```

### Gotchas

The organization rule **deny_all** expects a string "TRUE" and not a boolean `true`

Comment: while attempting to create a VM in terraform and adding it to the exceptions list creates a loop.

│ Error: Cycle: google_compute_instance.external_ip, google_org_policy_policy.exception_allow_public_ip

likely I need to use data resource